# How to play a video from storage in laravel

Tags: laravel, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I uploaded a video file in the storage folder and stored the path in database.

I want to play the video on the blade but it is not working

video.blade.php

```
<video controls>
   <source src="{{asset('storage/'. \App\Video::where('vid_id', $vid_id)->value('vid_path'))}}" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Path to the video

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/videos/2022_06_19_HmhR5cXugaEfvWe315Vi.mp4
```

The file uploads successfully but it does not play

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the public path for the video asset. What I'd suggest:

1. Check if you can access the video directly from the URL that you mentioned.
2. In your code snippet, remove
   `<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">`unless you have a movie.ogg resource of that format
3. Use url(), or public_path(), or asset() helpers to assign the src
   something like this:

   ```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="{{asset('path-to-your-video')}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
   ```